# jQuery select everything but a child div of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, children

I have the following HTML content:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="div-content">
        <div>
            <div class="div-botoes">
                <input id="bt1" type="button" tabindex="0" value="bt1">
                <input id="bt2" type="button" tabindex="0" value="bt2">
            </div>
            <ul class="divFormArea">
                <li id="li1">
                    <span><span>span</span></span>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="li2">
                    <span><span>span</span></span>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="li3">
                    <span><span>span</span></span>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div> lorem ipsum </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="li4">
                    <span><span>span</span></span>
                    <div>
                        <div id="dontWantThisDiv" class="dont-want-this-div">
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    Elements
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Elements
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script id="script">
                            ScriptContent
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span><span><span>a</span>c<span>b</span></span>d</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use a jQuery 1.9.1 selector that brings me everything on this content *except* the div `#dontWantThisDiv`.

I've tried lots of selectors but no one seems to select what I want. Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaburguer/QZ8KB)

Comment: Do you not want the children of `#dontWantThisDiv` or do you just not want that one div?

Comment: Have you tried looking through the [jQuery selectors docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)?

Comment: Something like this maybe: `$('.content, .content *:not(#dontWantThisDiv)')`?

Comment: You are looking for : `.content :not(#dontWantThisDiv, #dontWantThisDiv *)`. It exclude the div and it descendants.

Comment: If you select the parent of a child element, even if you haven't selected the child element itself, the selected parent's html will still contain the html of the child.

Comment: Your means of testing the result was weird. Your selector works just fine. That element is not included in the result. http://jsfiddle.net/QZ8KB/5/ Your description of the issue is using the term *"child/children"*, which is clearly not the proper term here. And I don't know if you also want to exclude descendants of the excluded one.

Comment: I believe your test condition to check for presence is of dontWantThisDiv is incorrect.

Comment: What about take all and throw away what you don't want? http://jsfiddle.net/CvS3k/

Comment: @Kyle I just don't want the entire div

Comment: @cookiemonster Yes, before posting

Comment: @War10ck didn't work :/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon didn't work too :/

Comment: @JasonP Ok, but still... is there a way to remove the content from the selector without removing from de DOM?

Comment: @cookiemonster All right but this is not an answer. I want all the html content whithout the div #dontWantThisDiv

Comment: @Ahmed Yeah :/ noticed that sorry about it

Comment: @HankLapidez I can't modify the DOM :/

Comment: Like that (see the `pre`) : http://jsfiddle.net/QZ8KB/8/?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yes, it worked like I asked. Thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the elements under .content except #dontWantThisDiv instead of the selector you can try this:-

```
var cloneHtml = $( ".content" ).clone().find('#dontWantThisDiv').remove();
console.log(cloneHtml.html())
```

Comment: It'll not remove the original html content from the dom, but you'll get all the content except the specific div and it's children.

Comment: Ok I will try It. If I can still do a bind (for the Telerik's Kendo UI) I will use your suggestion :)

Comment: It didn't work. When I remove this div that I don't want, the LIs and the UL and other DIVs are removed too :(

Comment: I've made something worng hahaha... this removes only the DIV like I asked, but yet... still not working when I call the Kendo UI bind. But I don't know why :/
Anyway, thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to return the entire DOM without the particular descendant node, your result literally will just contain the single top-level node (`<div class="content">`) anyway, regardless of whether you eliminate the descendant node or not.

If you are allowed to alter the HTML content itself, it would be much easier by using `$('#dontWantThisDiv').remove();` to remove that node from the DOM and keep everything else.

If you are not allowed to alter the HTML content, then maybe elaborate on your scenario and we can see if there is a more efficient technique to achieve it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't mod the DOM.
I'm using the Telerik's Kendo UI and I need to bind the DOM whithout that DIV otherwise it will throw an exception.
But I need that part of the DOM 'cause I'm bindind that with other kendo.observable object